# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, swing, javacv

I am trying to write a test program using Java CV.
This is the error I am getting.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\neel\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp28164099778499\jniopencv_core.dll:
>   Can't find dependent libraries

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you set up your class path to recognize the libraries that you're using?

Comment: I am a beginner in Java CV.Here is what I did. 
I downloaded the JavaCV 0.9 and Open CV 2.4.9. I extracted both in my C:\\   

What are the steps after this?

Comment: It all depends on how you're compiling and running your program. Are you running via an IDE or command line?

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to make the `.dll` accessible:

- Load the `.dll` explicitly in the source code:

  ```
  System.load("C:\Users\neel\AppData\…\jniopencv_core.dll");
  ```
- Specify the `java.library.path` on the [`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command line by using the `-D` option:

  ```
  java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\neel\AppData\…\jniopencv_core.dll" …
  ```
- Place your `.dll` in a directory that is in the [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), `java.library.path`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Thank you friends.
Apparently,the version and OpenCv and JavaCv should match.
Thank you !